# Make a SharePoint page that shows (REST GET) links and presents the results

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, javascript, web-part

Is it possible even for a SharePoint noob like me to make up a page with many links (which only return a simple JSON result like true or false) and show the result of the clicked link on the same page next to the link? I think this is a rather common use case and was hoping there is something out of the box but don't know where to look.

Comment: You have tagged your post with both `sharepoint-online` and `sharepoint-server`.  These are two different product versions of SharePoint, one being in the cloud, the other on-premises.  Which tag is correct?

Comment: @willman I'm such a noob I would not know for sure. But the address is companyxy.sharepoint.com, so I guess it is in the cloud and not on-premise.

Comment: Yes, that is most definitely `online`, can you tell whether your site is running in [classic mode or modern mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f)?

Comment: @willman By comparing the look of it, it's definitely the modern mode.

Comment: And to clarify your ask, when you say "show the result of the clicked link", are you planning on these links being to sites outside of SharePoint, or pages within your site, or to documents in a library on your site?  And you then want to display the corresponding page or document within the current page?

Comment: @willman The links reference to urls outside of SharePoint but inside the intranet - they are available for the user so javascript should able to reach them. The links return a json response and it would be enough to make this response visible on the SharePoint page somehow (a label, a mouseover, some other indicator). The page however must remember the outcome (the json result) until the SharePoint page is refreshed (the page may contain 40 links and when I clicked 20 links I will be able to check the result for the 20 links already visited).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to call Rest API with some links and retrieve the results to a filed in the page to display. Per my knowledge there are no out of the box web parts doing such work. The links web part holds the links and open the new page in a new tab.

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise, you may need to use a content editor/script editor web part to hold scripts or simply create a custom web part for your goal. Here is an example which you can have a check:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d9a06d93-93d2-4340-a491-c7d0d5d4fdf3/how-to-dynamically-change-link-in-page-viewer-web-part-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

For SharePoint Online, you may need to use use [SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to do so.